# theano 'as_op' with gpuArray

Tags: python, python-3.x, gpu, theano

I'm working on a simple theano `as_op`:

```
@as_op(itypes=[theano.tensor.lmatrix, theano.tensor.lvector, theano.tensor.lvector], otypes=[theano.tensor.lmatrix])#, infer_shape=infer_shape_numpy)
def increment_A(A, bmus_i0, i1):
    np.add.at(A, (bmus_i0, i1), 1)
    np.add.at(A, (i1, bmus_i0), 1)
    return A
```

It works only if i use cpu, when i try to use gpu i get the error

```
TypeError: We expected inputs of types '[TensorType(int64, matrix), TensorType(int64, vector), TensorType(int64, vector)]' but got types '[GpuArrayType<None>(int64, matrix), TensorType(int64, vector), TensorType(int64, vector)]'
```

Of course it wants a `gpuarray` as input...
How i can set correctly the input of the method?